# error de lectura PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf

estoy tratando de leer un documento pdf de texto (no es un escaneo de una imagen) sin embargo cuando trato de extraer el texto me devuelve:

'\n\x01\x02\x01„\x01ı\x01]\x01ˆ\x01\x02\x01˚\x01P\x01]\x01’\x01ı\x01„\x01\x02\x01o\n\x01„\x01˚\x01ˆ\x01]\x01}\x01„\x01\x0f\x01'

he probado a cambiar el encode pero ni con esas dejo a continuación mi código:

````
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
page = read_pdf.getPage(2)
page_content = page.extractText()
page_content```

No puedo compartir el documento pdf por privacidad de terceros, muchisimas gracias por adelantado!
````

Comment: Probé el código en un PDF que tengo y puede leerlo correctamente. Una posibilidad es que el PDF no sea legible. Un motivo es que la tipografía no está incrustada correctamente en el archivo y lo que ves son vectores (curvas) del texto. Una forma de comprobar esto es copiar el texto con ctrl+c, y pegarlo en un notepad. Si aparecen "garabatos", entonces ahí está el problema. También puedes revisar el archivo con Adobe Illustrator para comprobar. Si es el caso, deben revisar el sistema que está destilando esos PDF.